# What is the name of this technique to deal with outliers?

Tags: outliers

I've been exploring techniques to deal with outliers that may apply to my machine learning use case and have stumbled upon this [short video from Udacity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-oE175NJiQ).

In summary:

1. Train your machine learning model.
2. Remove X% of points with largest residual error.
3. Re-train model.

It seems as though it could apply to my use case, but of course more research into this technique and its pros, cons, consequences, assumptions, etc. are necessary.

As such I tried to search for it, but didn't get far; hence me asking this question here.

**What is the name of this technique to deal with outliers?**

*The little I know:*

- It's referred to as "Outlier - Rejection" in the video (@0:46):

  > So congratulations, you know about outlier rejection...
- I found this [blog post](http://napitupulu-jon.appspot.com/posts/outliers-ud120.html) which appears to be by the same person who narrated in that short video. Here it's instead named "Outlier Detection".
- Further searches for both of these terms were too general, i.e. providing definitions for outlier/anomaly detection.

Comment: The distinction between detection and rejection is that detection identifies outliers and rejection removes them from the data.  But the idea of removing a certain percentage of high residuals should not be recommended,  First of all the model could be wrong.  Second the observations should not be removed unless there is a good reason to think the data is erroneous.  Sometimes robust methods that reduce the effect of a few outliers may be acceptable.  Also if you remove X% of the cases with the highest residuals these residuals may not be unusually large.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks for those tidbits. That's the kind of information I want to read about and consider, and is why I'm trying to find this thing's name so I can search for it and learn more :P